# Prevent from ajax call in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi i am making my project in the asp.net,

**basic expected behaviour** -- fill form name , select master module(dropdown), select sub modules(dropdown), ajax passes id of submodule dropdown, create(submit).. it will submit all values,

**now code is behaves**---- fill form name, select master and submodule, while selecting submodule from second dropdown is calling the ajax call, and create action is called, so the form name and masterID(that is extracted from first dropdown) gone blank... so i need to prevent the ajax call to call the controller

Myform in razor view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Form</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FormName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FormName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FormName)
        </div>

        <select id="State" name="state"></select><br />
        <p>
            <input id="sbmt" type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

My ajax call

```
 $('#State').change(function () {
            var a = $('#State').val();
            var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/form/create",
                type: "POST",
                data: { __RequestVerificationToken: token, 'SubID': a }
            });

        });
```

My controller

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(Form form,  int SubID)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                form.CreatedBy = 1;
                form.SubId = SubID;
               form.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                form.ModifyBy = 1;
                form.ModifyDate = DateTime.Now;
                form.IsActive = true;
                form.IsDeleted = false;
                db.Forms.Add(form);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.MasterID = new SelectList(db.Departments, "MasterId", "ModuleName", form.MasterID);
            return View(form);
        }
```

Comment: "... i have another feilds in the form that needs to be submitted, please help me how can i prevent the ajax call from submitting values." So you need fields submitted or you are trying to prevent fields from being submitted.... which is it?

Comment: @zgood i update the question man, please have a look

Comment: I think maybe your Create Action to be a JsonResult and return json back to your page instead of the RedirectToAction you currently have.

Comment: can you please eleborate litle

Comment: Try looking [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx) about the JsonResult. If you return json instead of redirecting your fields won't go blank

Comment: i understand json result,  "If you return json instead of redirecting your fields won't go blank" i didnt get with this

Comment: Your `$('#State').change()` function is doing a post. If you don't want it to do a post, then remove the code. What do you actually want to happen when your select a value from `State`? You say you have 2 dropdowns (`module` and `submodule`) but your view code only shows one! Which one of these is `State`?

Comment: i want to store value  $('#State').val();  into the SubID field of Form table,  which acts as foreign key for this table..state dropdown's markup is like <select id="State" name="State"></select><br />  @StephenMuecke

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but why are you ajax posting in the change event when you say you don't want to? The best option is to have the property `int SubID` in your view model, but if not, then just change the name of the control to SubId - `<select name="SubId" ...>` The selected value will then post back to the parameter SubId in your action method when you click the submit button (and get rid of the javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, you want to be able to post back the value of the selected state when you submit the form.  The best approach would be to use a view model that includes the property `SubId` and bind your `dropdownlist` to that property (the `SubId` parameter in you POST method is then not necessary.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SubId, ....)
```

The alternative is to rename the control to `SubId` so it matches the parameter in your POST method

```
<select name="SubId" ...>
```

and delete the unnecessary javascript function `$('#State').change(function () {...`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way for you would be to use MVC's ajax helpers. Change your form like so:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "OnSuccess" }))
{
...
```

And afterwards add a javascript handler for onsuccess

```
function OnSuccess(){
   alert("success");
}
```

This is barely functional code just to get you started.

PS. Make sure you add a reference to ~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js

Comment: ok understand what are you saying as you can see my above code i have no success function, or i have to place all my ajaxy code into that function

Comment: The Ajax MVC helper doesn't work that great. It would be best to write your own ajax call. The Ajax helper relies on an old version of jQuery (1.5.1), jQuery unobtrusive lib, and a Microsoft ajax lib that is no longer supported. It need jQuery 1.5.1 because the unsupported Microsoft ajax lib relies on `live` instead of `on`

Comment: @zgood Latest version i found of microsoft ajax libs was 3.2.2, released with MVC 5.1. I find it very hard to believe that they still depend on an old version of jquery, where are you getting this from?

Comment: @zgood Latest version depends on jquery 1.8, anything else I might be missing?